# Formatting the received data from an api into an array React Axios

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios

I am new to react and I have designed a drop-down menu using react-select

```
const Locations = [
  { label: "Albania", value: 355 },
  { label: "Argentina", value: 54 },
  { label: "Austria", value: 43 },
  { label: "Cocos Islands", value: 61 },
  { label: "Kuwait", value: 965 },
  { label: "Sweden", value: 46 },
  { label: "Venezuela", value: 58 }
];

<Select placeholder='Select from pre-created Tags 'onChange={handleDropDown('Tags')} defaultValue={values.Tags} required options={Locations}/>
```

and I have received some data drom an api using axios:

```
 state = {
    locations:[],
    departments: [],
    tagsList:[],
  }

axios.get('/api/jobs/list-tags',{headers:headers}).then(respo =>{
      console.log(respo.data)
      this.setState({
        tagsList:respo.data
      })
      console.log(this.state.tagsList)
```

the data received from the api looks like this:

```
Object { id: 1, name: "MongoDB" }
Object { id: 2, name: "JavaScript" }
```

I want to replace the hardcoded data in Locations array with the info received from the api in the same format. (instead of `{ label: "Albania", value: 355 }, { id: 2, name: "JavaScript" }`). how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the response data:

```js
      this.setState({
        locations: respo.data.map(t=>({label: t.name, value: t.id}))
      })
```

Comment: yeah but what would I put here? options={Locations}

Comment: I mean locations not tagsList, my mistake.

Comment: yes but since this is in the setState, it gives me an error if I write it like options={locations} for example. ('locations' is not defined.) should it be like this.state.locations?

Comment: Yes, It should be ```this.state.locations```

Comment: Why i get negative signs!?!

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi the introduction to the solution sounded condescending, I replaced it with a link to documentation...